# Custom Button Action

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uibutton

I have 42 custom button on one View. How can I by pressing any of them edit of the created buttons that i want.

```
int a=0; int b=1;

int otstup=10;

for (int i=1; i<=42; i++) {
    CGRect frameBtn = CGRectMake(a+60+otstup, b+otstup, 45, 45);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:frameBtn];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EmptyCoin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:i];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
    a=a+50;
    if (i%7 == 0)
    {
        a=0;
        b=b+45;
    }
}
```

Comment: on clicking a button, Do you want to change the properties of that particular button? Please specify clearly what you want to do?

Comment: "by pressing any of them edit of the created buttons that i want." - huh? I don't understand.

Comment: I press the button 7. And the 8 button to change the picture. etc

Comment: But still the question is not very clear. What are you really asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)pressBtn:(id)sender{ 
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
if (btn.tag == 1){
 1st button tapped

} 
else if(btn.tag == 2)
{
 2nd button tapped
}  
}
```

By using above code you can differentiate different buttons

**Update**

You have to create one mutable array store all the buttons in that array. you can access that array in `pressBtn` method

```
int a=0; int b=1;

int otstup=10;

 for (int i=1; i<=42; i++) {
CGRect frameBtn = CGRectMake(a+60+otstup, b+otstup, 45, 45);
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:frameBtn];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EmptyCoin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTag:i];
[buttonAry addObject:button];

[self.view addSubview:button];
a=a+50;
if (i%7 == 0)
{
    a=0;
    b=b+45;
}
}
```

**Button action method**

```
-(void)pressBtn:(id)sender{ 
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
if (btn.tag == 7){

UIButton *editButton = [buttonAry objectAtIndex:btn.tag+1];
[editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} 

}
```